# Send wireless signal from a wireless relay to turn a wireless lamp on

Tags: rf, relay, wireless, wifi, remote

I have this wireless relay:
[image: Wireless relay module and remote control]

[image]

The receiver is connected to a pump which is on the 1st floor of our house and can be controlled from the 3rd floor of our house. We have a neighbor (my sister) who can also turn the pump on from their house (adjacent). The problem is that when the neighbor turns the pump on or it is turned on from the 3rd floor, we cannot hear the pump. So sometimes, when the receiver misses the signal from the remote control, the pump is actually not turned off. I am thinking about adding another receiver to the 3rd floor that will turn a wireless lamp on only when the pump is turned on. So the signal must be triggered only when the receiver actually receives a signal. This way, if the receiver of the pump misses a signal, it won't send a signal to the wireless lamp's receiver on the 3rd floor.

I can connect a single remote control both to the pump's receiver and the indicator lamp's receiver so that it will always turn the wireless lamp on. However, if the pump misses the signal since it's on the 1st floor, the indicator lamp can be misleading. So the lamp must be turned on only when the pump is turned on (i.e., the signal or the trigger of the signal must come from the pump's receiver).

The receiver module is already connected to our pump. I think I can also figure out how to connect a "device" to the receiver module that will be responsible for triggering a "press" on the remote control button shown in the screenshot to turn a wireless lamp on which is 7 meters away from the pump. The problem is identifying what that "device" would be and if it's even possible.

Is there a simple way to achieve this without using Arduino or microcontroller? Is there a way to automatically press a remote control button when the receiver receives a signal?

Comment: Wire the pump to the NO and put a BJT + pull resistor on NC for driving the light?

Comment: Thank you @Lundin. I am not sure if I understand though. Does the BJT + pull resistor trigger a "press" on the remote control shown in the screenshot that will turn the wireless lamp on? I have also updated my question above and the description.

Comment: You can have a NPN BJT with a pull-up on the base driving the light. If you connect the BJT base to NC and common=GND, then in the normal state the BJT will not conduct since it the gate is grounded. When the relay flips and the contact opens, the pull-up will pull the gate high and the NPN will conduct. But come to think of it you probably supply the pump through common, yeah? The BJT solution relies on common being GND. Also is the pump using VAC or VDC? Best not to tamper with non-isolated electronics there in case of VAC.

Comment: @Lundin The pump has its own receiver and the lamp has also its own separate receiver. The lamp is 6-7 meters away from the pump.